# How to Parse data packets in iOS Network Extension

Tags: swift, networkextension

I'm trying to parse the data packets in NEPacketTunnelProvider subclass but after trying different ways not able to parse the data.

```
        private func readPackets() {
        self.packetFlow.readPackets() { datas, protocolNumbers in
            self.sendPackets(datas, withProtocols: protocolNumbers)
            if let dataArray = datas as? [Data] {
                for dataPackets in dataArray {
                   let ipHeader =  self.processPacket(dataPackets, protocolNumber: 0)
                    self.headerData.append(ipHeader)
                }
            }
            self.readPackets()
        }
    }
   
        private func processPacket(_ rawData: Data, protocolNumber: NSNumber)-> IPHeader {
        let  data = BinaryData.init(data: rawData, bigEndian: true)
           
        let header = IPHeader(version: try? data.get(0),
                            headerLength: try? data.get(1),
                            typeOfService: try? data.get(2),
                            length: try? data.get(3),
                            id: try? data.get(5),
                            offset: try? data.get(7),
                            timeToLive: try? data.get(8),
                            proto: try? data.get(9),
                            checksum: try? data.get(10),
                            source: in_addr(s_addr: try! data.get(12)),
                            destination: in_addr(s_addr:try! data.get(16)))
        
      return header
    }
```

Comment: @CervezaEmperor  can you add something here???, It would be a great help.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using the BinarySwift library. You can find a code sample within the repos readme.

https://github.com/Szaq/BinarySwift

You first want to create your models for the headers that you want to extract. For example, if you're trying extract the IP header information from the packet, you need to create the following IP Header model.

```
   struct IPHeader {
      let version: UInt8
      let headerLength: UInt8
      let typeOfService: UInt8
      let length: UInt16
      let id: UInt16
      let offset: UInt16
      let timeToLive: UInt8
      let proto:UInt8
      let checksum: UInt16
      let source: in_addr
      let destination: in_addr
    }
```

Afterwards, you can start using BinarySwift to extract the packet data, where each hardcoded number represents the offset in bytes from the start of the data. You can find more information on how IPv4 headers are structured this from the link below.

https://searchnetworking.techtarget.com/tutorial/Routing-First-Step-IP-header-format

```
let binaryData = BinaryData(data: data, bigEndian: true)

let header = IPHeader(version: try data.get(0),
                headerLength: try data.get(1),
                typeOfService: try data.get(2),
                length: try data.get(3),
                id: try data.get(5),
                offset: try data.get(7),
                timeToLive: try data.get(8),
                proto: try data.get(9),
                checksum: try data.get(10),
                source: in_addr(s_addr: try data.get(12)),
                destination: in_addr(s_addr: try data.get(16)))
```

Keep in mind that you may need to bit shift some of the IP Header properties to get the correct value since some of the values are represented by less than 8 bits. You can follow this general format and do the same steps to extract the other headers.

Comment: so much for replying but i have one issue. I have implemented the model and added BinaryData method and tried to do something inside the the loop but one question will the self.headerData will be a array of IPHeader and also let ipHeader  is coming nil


`if let dataArray = datas as? [Data] {
                for dataPackets in dataArray {
                   let ipHeader =  self.processPacket(dataPackets, protocolNumber: 0)
                    self.headerData.append(ipHeader)
                }
            }`

Comment: Could you edit your original post and include the code that you’ve added? That way I can better answer your question. If your ipHeader variable is coming back as nil, either something is wrong in your processPacket method or you’re receiving an empty array of Data objects from the readPackets method. I would try to find which is causing this first.

Comment: Also whats the ipAddress and port i should provide in the VPN configuartion?. I tried to running UDPServer on some port but not able to get the IPAddress, if you can help me with that too, it would be great.

Comment: The ip address should be the ip of your device. The port can be anything as long as it doesn't conflict with other ports. Take this with a grain of salt however as I've only found my knowledge from trial and error myself.

Comment: Your self.headerData would only include ip headers since your processPacket method only returns ip headers. Each packet includes additional information and not only ip headers. For example, a packet could be 100 bytes long, where the first 20 bytes are IP header info, the next 20 bytes could be TCP header info, and the remaining bytes could be your raw HTTP.